# Flutter - do not wrap with text and container

Tags: list, flutter, dart, richtext, textspan

i have this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(mainApp());

class mainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Chat(),
    );
  }
}

class Chat extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState();
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  List<InlineSpan> myList = [
    TextSpan(text: 'Hello, my name '),
    WidgetSpan(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('tap');
          },
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text(
                'is',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    TextSpan(text: ' Gabriele, and i am 21 years old!'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.black),
            children: myList,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my current output:

[image]

as you can see in the image, the word 'is' (highlighted in orange) is slightly shifted upwards.

How can I get it to be on the same level as other words?
(for example by aligning everything in the center regarding the horizontal axis..)

.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably occurs because you are using `Padding` and you set

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0)
```

try this instead

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4, top: 4)
```